# Webform custom Options file location

Tags: webforms

My question is; When you create a custom option list in Webforms, where or how does the list get stored?

Explanation:
In the Webforms Module (8.x-5.0-rc13) you have the ability to create custom options lists. The Options configuration page lists reusable predefined options/values available for select menus, radio buttons, checkboxes and Likert elements. (example: gender, sizes). The option lists that are included when the module is installed can be found as a yml files in docroot>>modules>>webform>>config>>install. After creating a custom option list I can not find the files anywhere or find a table in the database with the vales.

WHY?
I have a list of 500 colleges that I want to populate a select list with different option values option text. pasting the list would be much easier and faster than using the interface to create the list.

I tried using a term select but cannot figure out how to define the value. I can only define the display text in the terms.

Sample yml code customized from one of the predefined option lists:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - webform
id: my_colleges
label: US Colleges
category: Demographic
likert: false
options: |
  361623: ALASKA PACIFIC UNIVERSITY
  362001: ANCHORAGE COMMUNITY COLLEGE
  362503: UNIVERSITY ALASKA
  362814: SHELDON JACKSON COLLEGE
  363495: UNIVERSITY ALASKA
```

Comment: This is stored in configuration, go to /admin/config/development/configuration/single/export and select the configuration type "Webform options" or export all config files and look for webform.webform_options.[id].yml

Comment: I cannot find the path you are referring to. I am using 8.x-5.0-rc13. I can find the files with webform.webform_options.[id].yml but only for the predefined option lists. the folder does not contain the created options list. ANd if you place a custom  yml file in the directory, the list does not display.

Comment: The path is a url: www.mysite.com/admin/config/development/configuration/single/export (you can also navigate to it in the admin ui)

Answer (score 1):

Webform options are config entities. You can export and import then via /admin/config/development/configuration.

You can also just bulk edit the options YAML. (/admin/structure/webform/config/options/manage/time_zones/source)

Or you can use hook_webform_options_alter() or hook_webform_options_WEBFORM_OPTIONS_ID_alter() to dynamic populate options from database or web service.